# centos + nginx + php.. how to?

Tags: php, centos, nginx

I currently have nginx installed and running on a CentOS server.

It's all good.

Now I'm trying to enable PHP but can't seem to find any clear tutorial ([even nginx's docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample)) that will explain it straightly.

I understood so far that it's composed of two components: PHP-CGI & FCGI.

What commands simply install it? Preferbly using "yum".

*Also, I want that nginx will pass data to PHP through a unix socket file, and not through TCP - performance wise.*

This [nginx's doc page](http://wiki.nginx.org/PHPFcgiExample) jumps, and is not suitable for someone who just starting to get to know these stuff, as myself.

I thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you find your answer here :
[CentOS 5.5 + PHP 5.3.3 + PHP-FPM + APC + nginx (yum RPMs)](http://rob.olmos.name/2010/08/centos-5-5-php-5-3-3-php-fpm-nginx-rpms/)

Comment: Excellent link! Thank you!! This guide though, doesn't get you MySQL support for PHP. In order to have it you need to include the "php53u-mysql" as well, in the "yum install" command.

Comment: Hi Behrooz - on this site we frown upon answers that only serve a single link, as when the link goes dead in the future, the answer becomes useless. Could you at least elaborate on the basic steps that are contained in the tutorial?

Comment: Dear Mark , I'm new to this site as you can see my profile. Okay , I will do it. thank you